# Print Calendar Booklet Style, so I can staple correctly

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, page-layout, booklet

Trying to assemble this calendar:

[image]

To be clear, this is an illustration of a screenshot of a zoomed out version of what I see in InDesign. There are 28 pages. I go to "Print Booklet" select "2-up Saddle Stitch" with a range of "1,2,27,28", and when I then go to "Xerox Features" and select "2-Sided Print Flip on Short Edge" the program closes when I try to print... "2-Sided Print" gave me the right order on the front page, but the back page was flipped upside down. To be clear, when I say "flipped up side down" I dont' mean each of the two individual pages on the back, I mean if the two pages on the back were grouped and you rotated 180 degrees. Does that make sense?

Here is what I want in preview:

[image]

Comment: Actually, the top right of the "RIGHT" preview window should be flipped upside down.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you want to flip on the *long* edge, but if you are having problems with duplex, try feeding it 2x

Answer (score 1):

Although I have used the booklet feature fairly often, I always get strange results when I try to print a range of pages, so there may be something related to the combo of booklet printing and printing a page range that messes things up.

With that said, your problem may be caused by the fact that you are asking both the InDesign print engine to convert to booklet, and also asking your printer driver engine to do the same thing.  Try just using the booklet print option in InDesign and leaving your default printer settings, and see if that works.